# "The Dancing Queen" is using dancing applicable here?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

I was watching a movie last night and It was a musical one. The movie involved a song named "**The Dancing Queen**".

Now, I know that the word "Dancing" is not an adjective. For instance, we say **Dance music** rather than **Dancing music**. I'm writing this to know if the name of the song was just to draw attention or there is some exception that makes it work as an adjective .

Answer (score 1):

*-ing* forms can function as adjectives and nouns - here's an example from *Practical English Usage*:

- *You're **smoking** too much these days* (verb: part of present progressive)
- *There was a **smoking** cigarette end in the ashtray* (adjective describing cigarette end)
- ***Smoking** is bad for you* (noun: subject of sentence)

The verb/adjective forms are called *present participles* and the noun form is called a *gerund*, and yes they look exactly the same. The difference is really in how they're being used - what's their role in the sentence?

*Dancing queen* could be read two ways I think - either describing a *queen* as *dancing* (describing what they're doing, as a verb/adjective form), or as another way of phrasing *the queen of dancing*, where *dancing* is a noun form and it's another way of saying *the queen of dance*.

And *dance music* and *dancing music* are really the same thing, I'd argue that *dancing music* used to be what people would call "music for dancing" in the past. Now *dance music* is used more as the name of a particular style or genre, but *dancing music* could still be used to describe music intended for formal dances, or things like *salsa* and *tango*.

Comment: Important to remember that ABBA were Swedish, and that many of their songs contain non-standard English usages.

Comment: This is completely normal English usage though. *Smoking gun*, *smoking jacket* etc.

Comment: Where have you ever heard of a 'dancing queen' outside of the ABBA song?

Comment: Why does that matter? We're talking about grammar here. If someone said *twerking coconut crab* you'd still understand what it meant even if you'd never seen those words combined before

Comment: I daresay that if someone at a railway station said 'I want to buy a travelling ticket' we'd know what they meant, but we would still note that is non-standard, even if we didn't tell them.